# How can I convert a 2D array to 1D functionally, in F#?

Tags: arrays, functional-programming, f#

I can do it easily if I use a mutable counter and 2 for loops but I want to do it inside the `Array.init` function.

This is it so far, I just need to change the zeroes in `array2D.[0, 0]`.

```
let array2D = Array2D.init 10 10 (fun i j -> 0)

let array = Array.init 100 (fun i -> array2D.[0, 0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite correct that you can use the combination of / and % to do this, such as:

```
// assume a 2d array array2d
let m = Array2D.length1 array2d
let n = Array2D.length2 array2d
let array1d = Array.init (m * n) (fun i -> array2d.[i / n, i % n]
```

That would be 'purely functional'.  Heavy use of division, and especially modulus, however, is not likely to be especially performant.  If performance is a concern, you would indeed be much better off doing something like:

```
// assume a 2d array array2d
let m = Array2D.length1 array2d
let n = Array2D.length2 array2d
let array1d = Array.zeroCreate (m * n)
for i = 0 to (m - 1) do
  for j = 0 to (n - 1) do
    array1d.[(i * n) + j)] <- array2d.[i,j]
```

F# is functional-*first*, not zealously-functional-only.  It's fine to use an imperative style when performance is a major concern.  That's why it's an option.  Probably best to turn the above into a referentially-transparent function, such as `make1darrayfrom2darray`:

```
let make1darrayfrom2darray array2d = 
    let m = Array2D.length1 array2d
    let n = Array2D.length2 array2d
    let array1d = Array.zeroCreate (m * n)
    for i = 0 to (m - 1) do
      for j = 0 to (n - 1) do
        array1d.[(i * n) + j] <- array2d.[i,j]
    array1d
```

If you are doing this a heck of a lot but your arrays are not long-lived (and especially if you need large arrays), [consider using](https://adamsitnik.com/Array-Pool/) [the ArrayPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1?view=netstandard-2.1) [system](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2017/05/31/arraypool/).  This will help your program avoid a lot of potentially expensive but unnecessary memory allocations.

Answer (score 1):

I thought about it some more, and got it right. Sorry for the quick post, should have just spent a bit more time on it.

```
array2D.[i / 10, i % 10]
```